# 301 redirect: SEO urls, same article ID

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched around and couldn't find an example such as this one.

To make a long story short, the news script i was using sucked and i switched to another one. i managed to copy the database tables all in to the new news script and so all of the article IDs are exactly the same as my old news script. Now I'm having issues redirecting the old urls.

My old links look like this, where the view-number represents the article id
`http://www.mysite.com/news/view-252-lots-of-friendly-url-text/`

My new links look like this where the -r number represent the article id
`http://www.mysite.com/page/view/cat/lots-of-friendly-url-text-r238`

If anyone out there can give me some pointers on how i can possibly redirect these with some wildcards it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news/view-([0-9]+)-(.+?)/?$ /page/view/cat/$2-r$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply Anubhava

Unfortunately, the rewrite you provided didn't work.

 After going through some documentation on the process i came up with the following that works only if i create a directory called news and place a fresh htaccess into the directory.

RewriteRule ^view-([0-9]+)-(.+[^/]) /view/tna-news/$2-r$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: I failed to mention that having the htaccess in my news directory interferes with my current news script.

Comment: You don't really need `news` directory. Is this the only code in your .htaccess or you have some more code here? If yes post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Yes i have more lines in my htaccess. Even with a clean htaccess, neither codes work.

Had a few others give it a shot. so far none of us have been able to get proper redirs to work at the root htaccess


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico)$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
Redirect 301 /portal.php http://www.site.com/
Redirect 301 /index.php?app=portal http://www.site.com/
Redirect 301 /portal/ http://www.site.com/